# What could cause Shape.Cut to fail in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a method in my macro that executes the following code:

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets("sheet1")
For each sh in myDocument.Shapes
    If sh.Name = "square" Then
        sh.Cut
    End If
Next
```

My problem is that the code causes an error on the line *sh.Cut*.  I know that there is a shape called "square" - I can see (visually) the shape in the document, but Excel just doesn't want to cut that shape out.  Any suggestions as to why this might be?

---

EDIT: To clarify, this behaviour does not always happen.  Usually it is alright - it only seems to happen sometimes, but I can't see any co-relation between the times that it happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an exception?  Or does it just not go away?

Comment: exception - added to question to clarify

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: hmm.. - not sure - I have made a couple of changes in my code in various places and it seems to have gone away (can't say what it was that fixed it - if it comes back I will be sure to post the error here)

Comment: You might want to qualify the Worksheets("Sheet1") reference with ThisWorkbook if that is appropriate for your situation. Otherwise you may get unexpected behaviour if a different workbook is active when the macro is run (e.g. via Tools > Macro > Macros)

Comment: Nah, only ever that workbook open

Answer (score 2):

There's only two reasons to ever use the Select method. 1) You want to select something.  2) You're working with shapes and getting weird errors.  It doesn't make sense, but try

```
sh.Select
sh.Cut
```

and I'll bet it will work every time.